# How to get a particular link from a specific class?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'd like to extract this **href** from that particular **class**

```html
<tr class="even">
    <td>
        <a href="/italy/serie-a-2015-2016/">Serie A 2015/2016</a>
    </td>
```

This is what I wrote:

```vb
Sub ExtractHrefClass()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim class As Object
    Dim href As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Range("D8")
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set doc = ie.document
    Set class = doc.getElementsByClassName("even")
    Set href = class.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Range("E8").Value = href
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

But unfortunately there is a mistake **Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)** on the line:

```vb
    Set href = class.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

**UPDATE 1**

I modified the code as per @RyszardJędraszyk answer, but no output come out O_o Where am I doing wrong?

```vb
Sub ExtractHrefClass()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim href As Object
    Dim htmlEle As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Range("D8")
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy = False
    Set doc = ie.document
    Set href = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each htmlEle In href
        If htmlEle.className = "even" Then
            Range("E8").Value = htmlEle
        End If
    Next
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2**

As @dee requested in comment, there is the code from the web page http://www.soccer24.com/italy/serie-a/archive/

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/italy/serie-a/">Serie A 2016/2017</a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>
            <a href="/italy/serie-a-2015-2016/">Serie A 2015/2016</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="team-logo" style="background-image: url(/res/image/data/UZbZIMhM-bsGsveSt.png)"></span><a href="/team/juventus/C06aJvIB/">Juventus</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/italy/serie-a-2014-2015/">Serie A 2014/2015</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="team-logo" style="background-image: url(/res/image/data/UZbZIMhM-bsGsveSt.png)"></span><a href="/team/juventus/C06aJvIB/">Juventus</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I need only to extract that line: `/italy/serie-a-2015-2016/`

Comment: Please don't post updates as answers, just edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.soccer24.com/italy/serie-a/archive/", False
    .Send
    MsgBox Split(Split(Split(.ResponseText, "<tr class=""even"">", 2)(1), "<a href=""", 2)(1), """", 2)(0)
End With
```

The procedure you need might look like:

```
Sub ExtractHrefClass()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Range("D8").Value, False
        .Send
        Range("E8").Value = Split(Split(Split(.ResponseText, "<tr class=""even"">", 2)(1), "<a href=""", 2)(1), """", 2)(0)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ALIENATO please click to accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim href As HTMLObjectElement
```

Make sure that proper libraries are checked in references (Microsoft HTML Object Library).

Are you sure that `doc.getElementsByClassName("even")` works? It is not listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926433.aspx as available method.

I always first use `getElementsByTagName` and make a condiction `If htmlEle.className = "even" then`.

Also add the following: `ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE and ie.busy = False`. Still if it is some AJAX based website it can be not enough to determine that website has fully loaded (from the link guessing it could be flashscore.com where you need to track elements on the website informing about its loading status).

Comment: `Dim href As HTMLObjectElement` not works, and i have **Microsoft HTML Object Library** inserted. Now i'ill try to modify the code, just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` can be used here to select the `anchor` elemets inside of the `tr` with the specific `class` and then with `getAttribute("href")` the `href-attribute` can be retrieved. HTH.

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim ie As Object
Dim name As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = 1

ie.navigate "<URL>"
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
Set Doc = ie.document

Dim anchors As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Dim anchor As IHTMLAnchorElement
Dim i As Integer

Set anchors = Doc.querySelectorAll("tr[class~='even'] a")

If Not anchors Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To anchors.Length - 1
        Set anchor = anchors.item(i)
        If anchor.getAttribute("href") = "/italy/serie-a-2015-2016/" Then
            Range("E8").Value = anchor.innerHTML
        End If
    Next
End If
ie.Quit
```